# How to paginate hive table in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I wanted to do a pagination on a hive table having ~1.5 billion rows using pyspark. I came across one solution using ROW_NUMBER(). When I tried it, I am running out memory. Not sure whether spark is trying to bring in the complete table to it's memory and then doing a pagination.

After that, I came across this LIMIT clause in Hive SQL (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause) and tried it. But it failed in spark, the reason which I figured out was that hiveQL is not completely supported in spark.sql(). Spark SQL limit does not support multiple arguments for offset -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-limit.html

Is there a good approach where in I can do pagination using spark?

PS: The hive table does not have an ID column, with which I can sort and do a pagination. :)

Comment: you want to paginate the output of a `collect` ?

Comment: nope. The collect() when applied on ROW_NUMBER() query is taking up time. Hence, wanted to check whether any other query can be executed for pagination

Comment: if you just want a portion of your data, you can use `show`.

Comment: show() is for printing right? My use case is to convert the rows from the source to another format, after doing some operations on it.

Comment: Spark is not made to transfer data to python. Of course, you can do it with `collect` but the whole purpose is to read data, transforme them and write the data somewhere with `df.write`. 

So I do not understand what you want to do ...

Comment: if you could explain exactly what you want to do, we could find a real solution ... pagination is clearly not what you are looking for. Again, that's another [xy_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) !

Comment: My use case is to read a Hive table, do some operations on each row, write it to another database.

Answer (score 0):

basic use of spark :

```py
# Extract the data
df = spark.read.table("my_table")

# Transform the data
df = df.withColumn("new_col", some_transformation())

# Load the data
df.write ... # write wherever you want
```

Comment: My use case was to write the data to another database itself. An amazon aurora db

Comment: and ? you have plenty of connector to connect spark to other dbs ... what your problem?

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen amazon aurora is mysql right ? you can write using jdbc.

Comment: I also have use cases where in, I will read N rows from a Hive table.. and will be doing a complex reduce function on top of all the rows. And only writing that reduced result to DB

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen Yes and ? Again, that's not an issue. Come back with a real issue. I do not see currently what is blocking you.

Comment: I'll probably come back with some code and explain the issues I am facing. Thanks